# How to return a value in one method to another method of the same class

Tags: c++, return-value

I have this two code samples `Employee.h` and `Employee.cpp`

`Employee.h` is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#define SIZE 20

class Employee{
private:
    double othrs, otrate,salary;
protected:
    int Empno;
    char name[SIZE];
    int telephone;
    double basicSalary;
public:
    Employee();
    ~Employee();
    double calcNetSalary(double basicSalary,double othrs, double otrate);
    void displayNetSalary();
};
```

And here's my `Employee.cpp`

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Employee.h"
using namespace std;

Employee::Employee(){

}
Employee::~Employee(){

}
double Employee::calcNetSalary(double basicSalary,double othrs, double otrate){
    double salary=(basicSalary+othrs*otrate);   
    return salary;
}
void Employee::displayNetSalary(){
    cout<<"Net Salary : "<<salary; //This line doesn't print the correct value but some other values (**6.01347e-154**)
}
```

And here's my `Main.cpp`

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Employee.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    Employee *emp=new Employee();
    emp->calcNetSalary(10,20,30);
    emp->displayNetSalary();
return 0;
};
```

And is there a way I could use the returning value(salary) in `calcNetSalary(double basicSalary,double othrs, double otrate)` in `displayNetSalary()` method?

Comment: Need to initialize the values

Comment: you just need call calcNetSalary in displayNetSalary !

Comment: @JakeFreeman: I have initialized value in the `Main.cpp`

Comment: @user8794865 you never assign the instance variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to use this which assigns the value to the instance variable not a temporary variable:

```
double Employee::calcNetSalary(double basicSalary,double othrs, double otrate){
    salary=(basicSalary+othrs*otrate);   
    return salary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning value to a local variable within calcNetSalary function. Assign the value to your private member variable salary

Another option is to call calcNetSalary within displayNetSalary function

Comment: How do I assign the value to my private member variable salary? Can you show me an example?

Comment: Check my answer @user8794865

Comment: @user8794865 I would recommend you to go through C++ reference docs before posting your questions